# What is a word for how a family thinks of itself

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

Is there a word or expression that properly describes the general way the members of a family thinks of itself, including it’s history, social legends etc. The family could think of itself as being proud, independent, warlike, generous,  supportive of liberal causes etc.

Comment: Are you talking about a family's heritage?

Comment: As with an individual, that would be [*the family's **self-image***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22the+family%27s+self-image%22)

Comment: It sounds like a familial heritage  - a clade-group analog of a cultural identity.  Clade identity perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the **"familial tradition"** that is pertaining to or characteristic of a family. It refers to family history or behavior passed from generation to generation.